# Laravel dusk coming back to original browser tab or close latest tab but keep original

Tags: laravel, testing, automated-tests, laravel-dusk

I have situation where I need to click the link and visit new tab and see if there is that particular text or not and then come back to original tab and perform some work.

this is the code I am using to confirm I am in latest browser tab after clicking view button

```
$window = collect($this->driver->getWindowHandles())->last();
            $this->driver->switchTo()->window($window);
```

Now I have to come to original tab, How can i do that ? Any help?
is there any way to close recent tab after some time. so that i can come to original tab.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track.

You can continue with something like this:

```php
$this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
    $browser->visit('/')->click('@some-link');

    // switch to the last tab
    $window = collect($browser->driver->getWindowHandles())->last();
    $browser->driver->switchTo()->window($window);

    // make some assertion on that tab
    $browser->assertRouteIs('some-route.alias');

    // switch back to first tab
    $window = collect($browser->driver->getWindowHandles())->first();
    $browser->driver->switchTo()->window($window);
    
    // TODO: make further assertions
});
```